# to_sql - "cannot use a string pattern on a byte-like object"

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pypyodbc

I am trying to use pandas, sqlalchemy and pypyodbc in order to write my dataframe (df2) to a table in my sql database. I have successfully connected to the database with pypyodbc. However, when I try to use the engine with to_sql it throws the error in the title. I think I'm missing something in the urllib section when the engine creation string is parsed.

Here is my code snippet:

```
connStr = "Driver=SQL Server Native Client 10.0; Server=Sname-L\SQLEXPRESS;database=DBname;trusted_connection=yes;"

connEncodedStr = urllib.parse.quote_plus(connStr)

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(connEncodedStr),module=pypyodbc,echo=True)

df2.to_sql('db_table2', engine, if_exists='replace')

print(engine)
```

result:

```
Engine(mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=Driver=SQL Server Native Client 10.0; Server=Sname-L\SQLEXPRESS;database=DBname;trusted_connection=yes;)
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\s
qlalchemy\pool.py", line 1122, in _do_get
     return self._pool.get(wait, self._timeout)
   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\s
qlalchemy\util\queue.py", line 145, in get
     raise Empty
sqlalchemy.util.queue.Empty
```

However, this also happened:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "noaadatamanip_datafram.py", line 50, in <module>
    df2.to_sql('db_table2', engine, if_exists='replace')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\p
andas\core\generic.py", line 1201, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
```

The above code went on for a lot of lines and returned the error in the title. Let me know if posting the whole thing will be helpful.

Sorry in advance, my error handling skills are very low.

Comment: It would help for you to show us the traceback from the error in the title which `to_sql()` gives you.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? line 47, in <module>
    df2.to_sql('db_table2', engine, if_exists='replace')
line 1201, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
line 470, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
line 1147, in to_sql
    table.create()

Comment: That looks like part of a stack traceback. Edit the question to include the full traceback, and be sure to format it as code so that we see the exact line breaks which Python showed you. Thanks.

Comment: No need to add odbc connection string in your engine connection. See [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc)

Comment: I removed "odbc_connect=", however when I did that, it returned: 
    sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pypyodbc.Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC
Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified')